# Qt3D How to move the rotation axis to the centre of the object?

Tags: qt, projection, qt3d, 3dcamera

I am working on a simple 3D application where I am rotating the 3D object based on the Quaternion values that I read from the MPU6050 sensor.

I used the below code from simple-qml example as reference:

```
Entity {
id: sceneRoot

property real x: 0.5
property real y: -0.5
property real z: 0.5
property real w: 0.5

onWChanged: console.log("3W: "+w)
onXChanged: console.log("3X: "+x)
onYChanged: console.log("3Y: "+y)
onZChanged: console.log("3Z: "+z)


Camera {
    id: camera
    projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
    fieldOfView: 90
    nearPlane : 0.1
    farPlane : 100
    position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 40.0 )
    upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
    viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
}

FirstPersonCameraController { camera: camera }

components: [
    RenderSettings {
        activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
            camera: camera
            clearColor: "transparent"
        }
    },
    InputSettings { }
]

PhongMaterial {
    id: material
}

Mesh
{
    id: arrowMesh
    source: "/3dObj/resources/3dObj/arrow.obj"

}

Transform
{
    id: arrowTransform

    //Default/Reset position
    //Arrow head facing towards the screen
    //x:90,y:90,z:0
    property int eXAngle: 90
    property int eYAngle: 90
    property int eZAngle: 0

    rotation:
    {
        //MPU6050 gives values in quaternion
        Qt.quaternion(sceneRoot.w,sceneRoot.x,sceneRoot.y,sceneRoot.z)


    }
    scale: 0.05

}
Entity {
    id: sphereEntity
    components: [ arrowMesh, material, arrowTransform ]

}
}
```

The problem I am facing is that rotation happens around the head of the arrow (3D object) instead the centre of the arrow and also the object for certain quaternion values zooms.

What are the things I need to change so that I can rotate the object alone around its center without any zoom effects?

Also, I tried the three **projectionType**s as well.

I need the 3D to behave like the one in the youtube link below:
[Arduino MPU6050 example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyX9cRxJNdo)

Comment: Translate the arrow before rotating it, to center it around the origin.

Comment: Can you please provide some example? Where do I translate? Translation moves the object in 3D space right?

Comment: Yes, translation moves the object. Depending on what's the order of transformations - either add a `translation:` property to the `Transform`, or calculate the matrix yourself.