# How can I shift the Rotation Axis of imported model? (QML, QtQuick3D, View3D)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick3d

## Introduction

In my QtQuick (QML) project I need to use 3D model of dice (a cubic one) that should be rotated during animation process. I use View3D, because rotating dice will be inside of 3D-insertion which is inside my 2D project. I have downloaded a free-to-use dice model (.fbx) and successfully imported it in my project in form of ".mesh" file via Balsam Asset Import Tool. By choosing created mesh for a source of model and also applying the texture of dice via PrincipledMaterial, I perfectly see my dice model inside View3D.

## The problem

When I tried to animate the rotation process of model, I noticed, that dice rotates incorrectly. I decided to look its axis via QtQuick3D.Helpers' AxisHelper and saw that starting points of axes X and Y located just fine but the Z axis' starting point is shifted from the center of the model by about 10 units.

## What did I try

I tried to look up for useful properties of `Model` QML type (and `Node` because `Model` inherits `Node` type) that may allowed me to modify or specify the rotation axis of the object but I did not find anything. On the Stack Overflow there is one similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207675/qt3d-how-to-move-the-rotation-axis-to-the-centre-of-the-object) but it does not helped me, because I should use View3D, not the whole Qt3D with `Entity`. Moreover, I tried to put `translate` property but it has only x and y fields and I did not seen any changes by modifying these.

## What I want to know

I would like to know if there is a way to place rotation axis of 3D model inside the center of it. May be some [Balsam Asset Import Tool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick3d-tool-balsam.html)'s options can help me with that (I tried some options like dropNormals, removeComponentNormals, fbxPreservePivots but did not seen any changes)?
Also I am not good at 3D Modelling, so could you please tell me if .mesh or .fbx files of 3D models store the information of axis rotation or something like that.

[One group of axes is a 3D scene axes, and other group is dice model axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8daW.png)

## The code I have (View3DArea.qml - custom type)

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick3D
import QtQuick3D.Helpers

Rectangle
{
    id: root
    width: parent.width/1.5
    height: width
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "lightgrey"

    View3D
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Node
        {
            PerspectiveCamera
            {
                id: _camera
                z: 100
            }
            DirectionalLight
            {

            }
            // Applying the texture
            PrincipledMaterial
            {
                id: _priDiceMaterial
                baseColorMap: Texture
                {
                    source: "assets/assets/Dice_Diffuse.jpg.png"
                }
            }
            // Model information
            Model
            {
               id: _diceModel
               source: "/assets/assets/dice_001.mesh"
               materials: [_priDiceMaterial]
               eulerRotation: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
               position: Qt.vector3d(20, 20, 20)
               
               AxisHelper {} // Visual axes of dice model
            }
            
            AxisHelper { id: _sceneAxis } // Visual axes of 3D scene
        }
    }

    WasdController
    {
        controlledObject: _camera
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]

I reworked the answer by putting the `Model` inside the `Node`. You can change the axis of your `Model` by setting `x`, `y` or `z` properties. Then you apply rotation on the `Node`:

```
            Node
            {
                id: node
                Model
                {
                    id: _diceModel
                    source: "/assets/assets/dice_001.mesh"
                    materials: [_priDiceMaterial]
                    x: 100
                    y: 100
                    z: 100
                }
                eulerRotation: Qt.vector3d(0, 45, 0)
            }
```

Because `dice` is involved. I experimented with mixing `#Cube` and `#Cylinder` to create a dice effect. The approach uses the above strategy by offsetting the `#Cylinder` in different places. A pain point with this approach is, on certain faces, the `#Cylinder` needs to be rotated.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick3D
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    property color blk: Qt.rgba(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.75)
    property color wht: Qt.rgba(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.75)
    property color red: Qt.rgba(0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 0.75)
    Node {
        id: standAloneScene
        DirectionalLight { ambientColor: Qt.rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) }
        Node {
            id: node
            Model {
                source: "#Cube"
                materials: [
                    DefaultMaterial { diffuseColor: blk }
                ]
            }
            // 6
            Dot { x: -25; y: 50; z: -25 }
            Dot { x: 25; y: 50; z: -25 }
            Dot { x: -25; y: 50 }
            Dot { x: 25; y: 50 }
            Dot { x: -25; y: 50; z: 25 }
            Dot { x: 25; y: 50; z: 25 }
            // 1
            Dot { y: -50; c: red }
            // 4
            Dot { x: 50; y: -20; z: -25; r: "z"; c: red }
            Dot { x: 50; y: 20; z: -25; r: "z"; c: red }
            Dot { x: 50; y: -20; z: 25; r: "z"; c: red }
            Dot { x: 50; y: 20; z: 25; r: "z"; c: red }
            // 3
            Dot { x: -50; y: -20; z: -25; r: "z" }
            Dot { x: -50; r: "z" }
            Dot { x: -50; y: 20; z: 25; r: "z" }
            // 2
            Dot { z: 50; x: 20; r: "x" }
            Dot { z: 50; x: -20; r: "x"  }
            // 5
            Dot { z: -50; x: -25; y: -25; r: "x"  }
            Dot { z: -50; x: 25; y: -25; r: "x"  }
            Dot { z: -50; r: "x"  }
            Dot { z: -50; x: -25; y: 25; r: "x"  }
            Dot { z: -50; x: 25; y: 25; r: "x"  }
        }
        OrthographicCamera {
            id: cameraOrthographicFront
            lookAtNode: node
            y: 800; z: 1000
        }
    }
    View3D {
        anchors.fill: parent
        importScene: standAloneScene
        camera: cameraOrthographicFront
    }
    NumberAnimation {
        target: node
        property: "eulerRotation.y"
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        running: true
        from: 720; to: 0
        duration: 10000
    }
    NumberAnimation {
        target: node
        property: "eulerRotation.x"
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        running: true
        from: 360; to: 0
        duration: 10000
    }
}

// Dot.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick3D
Model {
    property string r: ""
    property color c: wht
    source: "#Cylinder"
    materials: [
        DefaultMaterial { diffuseColor: c }
    ]
    scale: Qt.vector3d(0.2, 0.05, 0.2)
    eulerRotation.x: r === 'x' ? 90 : 0
    eulerRotation.y: r === 'y' ? 90 : 0
    eulerRotation.z: r === 'z' ? 90 : 0
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAKX3ictVbdb9owEH/nr7DYQ1eppCk0LQ1CUwWaNGnt1k7ay7QHk5hg4djs4qzA1P99l4R8m0KrzQ8W+H6/+7JzdzxcKdDkQT/E3Ft2eO2vNVFSgxJR43ww7XylASN/OgTXjHrLAFQsfZc8Mk9TGQiUEU8JBS7pvhteDoc3Tpc8p/AVqBUDvcnkZCaWLuq1IJjR97bVPyPV7do5NZGeFrpKuk6h5WYmAfNbpLale+XngSWLIyfCkPxboST75jHJCtmUA4bLlaTiMw8WGmOm4YwzqSdZ6LmxC8s+I7XtdJcMg8XcqsTj2uEdHogGMFmRisFjSaIn8Yx1W/KQagacisglP1rCNA42p7HQdzschuHz+TyO2C4MvKKKu/n6WTupy8/PyVXtYKqS7Kxd0us7I7JxiWOPyDb926AWyKOBpcqDqg6rSI0d61QLh3FfGIjI6CUUz00eYZtzaTaWUBJqv0jBiCQf1La7R1WT+WZibvKtFg/yMOjBnqvYH/Xe20soR0BM/rX96hs0bLMA15mChLk2myqBvQqybcQxc3sF2dklwdmnpMV5LeVItbkrr/fEzCh/fQG9UAHQ1YJ7ExoyoIYq6KWCKvQjYFOq4YRSy1udlFFD1URHhnZ26xe2bTf8yPbvnD0NphXrVHoLBZE150K4ZEWBVUxmvTBtBft7Q+b3y/5nxu/jcMbgVnKs09hLKl5oCgHTjZjypoaJZbFg8Kh0yrM2ZeXHhKyw2hc6rU9yziXXpRaIpeQycImGuDydgwpdcp28XK1cUibLjyFVlOXQ/g/er/+V94OrI71/7nTwQ8THa/0KRWPAac871eZbzBWRBnQjfeRd08SBpQ8nlVRSadIbwaXPIGMYm/Ohhuztkp+14MijgqXDxm8cRxQM/HyOsp10vMkGm0a+sSqT8XhMTtYn5AO5sUmescarKnCbF3HbAret4J7/AsrMksI=)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sir. I have understood my mistake on that one, but it seems that position does not affect the axes of Model (I have tested this right now). I think it is not a translation like translate property from the Transform QML type. I do not know how exactly axes of models are placed relative to Model when it is created. For example, when I use built-in model of a cube (source: "#Cube"), its axes placed in the center of model. The problem still remains.

Comment: Can you share the model? gist or github?

Comment: Here is my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AlekseyLapunov/QML-Quick3D-Custom-Models). In the [assets](https://github.com/AlekseyLapunov/QML-Quick3D-Custom-Models/tree/master/assets) directory you can find .fbx file of dice model and .mesh file that was created via Balsam tool.

Comment: Thanks @fever. I had problems loading your model, but, anyhow, I updated my answer. I hope it helps.